# What does "myBody.velocity.y" mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would love to know what this is and how does it work on C# 2D unity game.

`myBody.velocity.y`

Comment: This are the properties of object myBody. Object myBOdy has a velocity property which in turn has a y property

Comment: Do you know C#? Do you know any other language? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1967458/1997232) and maybe some arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3391854/1997232).

Comment: I am still a beginner, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

If you look the reference page you can see the following note at the bottom of the page :

> Note: A velocity in Unity is units per second. The units are often thought of as metres but could be millimetres or light years. Unity velocity also has the speed in X, Y, and Z defining the direction.

Complete reference [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)